# Save ListBox Multiselection to single Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a userform where users can edit entries from a list selection and save them to specific cells.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
   Dim lZeile As Long

     If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

     If Trim(CStr(TextBox_Name.Text)) = "" Then
         MsgBox "Sie müssen mindestens einen Namen eingeben!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "FEHLER!"
         Exit Sub
     End If
     lZeile = 2 
     Do While Trim(CStr(Tabelle4.Cells(lZeile, 1).Value)) <> ""
         If ListBox1.Text = Trim(CStr(Tabelle4.Cells(lZeile, 1).Value)) Then

             Tabelle4.Cells(lZeile, 1).Value = Trim(CStr(TextBox_Name.Text))
             Tabelle4.Cells(lZeile, 11).Value = ListBox_Problem.Text
             Tabelle4.Cells(lZeile, 12).Value = TextBox_Problem2.Text
             Tabelle4.Cells(lZeile, 4).Value = ComboBox1.Text
             Tabelle4.Cells(lZeile, 3).Value = ComboBox2.Text
             Tabelle4.Cells(lZeile, 13).Value = TextBox3.Text
             Tabelle4.Cells(lZeile, 14).Value = TextBox4.Text
             If ListBox1.Text <> Trim(CStr(TextBox_Name.Text)) Then
                 Call UserForm_Initialize
                 If ListBox1.ListCount > 0 Then ListBox1.ListIndex = 0
             End If
             Exit Do
         End If
         lZeile = lZeile + 1
     Loop

End Sub
```

Now I have a ListBox where multiple entries can be selected. I want to write the selected entries into one single cell with "," as delimiter.

I have found the following code for that:

```
Dim i As Long

    sText = ""
    Range("B34").Value = ""
    With Me.ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                sText = sText & ", " & .List(i)
            End If

Next i
   End With

    sText = Mid(sText, 3)

    If Len(sText) > 0 Then
        Range("B34").Value = sText
    Else
        MsgBox "No selection made.", vbInformation
   End If
```

I tried to incorporate it into mine but just cannot get it to work. I am not that fluent with VBA and was wondering if someone could help me?

Comment: What's the trouble?

Comment: @user11982798 Primarily  my lack of knowledge. Because I do not understand how the second one works. I get the first one but I do not know how to combine them..

Comment: Ok I understand now, maybe, you want to combine your code with found code.

Comment: @user11982798 that is excatly what I would like to do. Ideal would be if I could understand what exactly the second one is doing so I am able to do it myself next time.

Comment: The second one Will check all collection list items that selected to concate with comma separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to put your code (minor changes made) into a function:

```
Public Function GetCommaSeparatedListBoxItems(ByVal FromListBox As MSForms.ListBox) As String
    Dim sText As String

    With FromListBox
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1 'loop through all items in the ListBox
            If .Selected(i) Then 'chech each item if it is selected and if so …
                sText = sText & ", " & .List(i) '… append this item comma delimited to `sText`
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    'since `sText` is empty in the beginning, data will always start with a comma, so removo that
    'example data before:        ", Item 1, Item 2, Item 3"
    sText = Mid$(sText, 3)
    'example data afterwards:    "Item 1, Item 2, Item 3"

    'return the comma separated items in the function
    GetCommaSeparatedListBoxItems = sText

    'Alternatively instead of the lise above you can …
    If Len(sText) > 0 Then 'check if something was selected in the listbox and  …
        GetCommaSeparatedListBoxItems = sText '… return the value
    Else
        MsgBox "No selection made.", vbInformation '… or a error message
    End If
End Function
```

That you can easily use like:

```
Debug.Print GetCommaSeparatedListBoxItems(FromListBox:=Me.ListBox1)
```

Example to write it into a cell you can use the function (in your first code) like:

```
Tabelle4.Cells(lZeile, 14).Value = GetCommaSeparatedListBoxItems(FromListBox:=Me.ListBox1)
```

you just need to adjust the code `Me.ListBox1` to your multi select ListBox.

Comment: Thank you @Pᴇʜ for your help! But how do I write the items into the cell in the same way I did it in the upper code? I tried to understand how the second one works but I just do not get it what exactly the code is doing. I found it online.

Comment: @VincenzoKöstler Have a look, I added some helpful comments into the code.

Comment: No problem, whenever you have to re-use code multiple times it is best practice to write it as a function (if it returns a value) or procedure/sub (if it does not return a value). Also a good practice is that one function/procedure just does one thing, and then name the function after what it does `GetCommaSeparatedListBoxItems` this way your code becomes very clean and easy human readable. Also it is much easier to test and debug 5 small procedures than 1 big spaghetti code.

Comment: Very good to know, I will keep that in my mind from now on. Also this makes combining code elements much easier it seems!

Really great tipps, thank you very much.